# Why doesn't Dictionary<TKey, TValue> have an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ctor?

Tags: .net, generics

Okay - so I know it's simple to build a factory method that provides the functionality; but given that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, shouldn't it have a Ctor equivalent to, for example, `List<T>`'s `ctor(IEnumerable<T> range)`?

It's even sillier given that it provides a Ctor that takes an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` as a source, but since that interface is also `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, the IEnumerable option would surely have made more sense; unless the `IEnumerable<>` interface wasn't around when the class first designed.

It get's worse because if you look at the implementation of the IDictionary version of the ctor - the input dictionary is imported with the following code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in dictionary)
{
    this.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Anyone think of a good reason for why the framework designers chose the most specific interface when a base interface was all that was required?

***Edit***

@Mark Seeman suggests that it's to avoid Exceptions being raised by duplicate keys - which is probably close to the truth - but consider this example:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void How_To_Break_The_IDictionary_Ctor_Design_Decision()
{
  Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dictionary.Add("hello", "world");
  dictionary.Add("Hello", "world");

  Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(dictionary,
                                   StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

I know - the test's in reverse - but for some reason I thought it made my point better :)

Given that the Key comparer is not part of the IDictionary interface, you can *never* guarantee that the dictionary you're importing will not generate duplicate keys, and therefore an `ArgumentException`, in constructing the new one.

Ergo - you might as well just have an IEnumerable constructor that does the same thing.

Comment: I requested the same thing for Guava recently: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=320

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Totally **unofficial guess**:

If a constructor allowed an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` you would have been able to supply multiple items with the same key and what would be the expected behavior of that?

E.g. you could have done something like this:

```
var kvps = new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Foo"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Bar"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Baz")        
}
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>(kvps);
```

You could argue that this should simply throw an exception to be consistent with the behavior of the Add method, but I would guess that the design team thought it would be a greater source of confusion than actually useful...

Comment: As more in the same vein, we can see that `Dictionary` also 'lacks' an `AddRange` - for a similar reason perhaps?

Comment: Whilst this might not be the official reason, it's good enough to justify the absence of the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` constructor.

Comment: +1 That's a good point - and probably quite close to the truth. However if that was the design decision then it's a flawed one: I could pass in a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> instance that uses a less restrictive IComparer (e.g. the default StringComparer versus the case-insensitive one) than the new one which could still generate an exception. One IDictionary does not necessarily another IDictionary make.

Comment: They probably should have left out the constructor overload that takes an IDictionary *and* a comparer. The architect responsible for this has probably been kicked upstairs by now. :->

Comment: "They probably should have left out the constructor overload that takes an IDictionary and a comparer" - I disagree.  If you want to copy a dictionary that's using a custom comparer, then you need this constructor.  Obviously you wouldn't want to copy to a dictionary that's using a *different* comparer, but people who use advanced features like comparers will be expected to know this.

Comment: @Joe - I agree that they should not have left out the constructor; but what about code that doesn't know where that Dictionary, or IDictionary comes from?  In any case, the ctor that takes an IDictionary and an IEqualityComparer is next to useless if the intention is to clone a new one that uses the same comparer as the input dictionary.  If all you have is the IDictionary instance, then you can't actually obtain it's key comparer.  What they should've done is to put the IEqualityComparer in as a property of IDictionary<Tkey, TValue>

Comment: @Mark Seeman - I'm marking this as the answer as I believe you've nailed the thinking behind the architecture; which therefore does answer the question. However - I think we can see that it was indeed flawed thinking!

Comment: @Andras "What they should've done is to put the IEqualityComparer in as a property of IDictionary<Tkey, TValue>" - again I disagree.  I think it's right that the IDictionary interface contains the minimal API needed to use a class as a dictionary.

Comment: @Joe - of course - you're right; I think ultimately this IDictionary ctor should be done away with - because it pupports to provide guarantees to the caller that it cannot guarantee.  Therefore it should be demoted to the IEnumerable one, with the IEqualityComparer overload also included.  to me, that would make sense.  In the meantime, I'll just use a factory method!

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static Dictionary<T, U> ToDictionary(
      this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, U>> source)
  {
    return source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
  }
```