# Why does dict allow duplicate inserts?

Tags: f#

why in the world does the constructor for a dictionary in `F#` allow duplicate keys and just overwrites silently?

```
let ``you just got dict`` = dict [ "hello","goodbye";"hello","world"]
```

This is very counter-intuitive behavior.

Comment: I would assume that this behavior was chosen because it doesn't throw runtime exception. And it's somehow consistent with `Item` property behaviour of Dictionary class

Comment: the C# collection initializer doesn't follow this behavior.

Comment: Yes. Probably that behavior was chosen because exception handling is not preferred error handling mechanism in F#

Comment: @Petr the C# behavior is consistent with the behavior of the Add method (because it's actually syntactic sugar for calling that method).  F#, being a language with different priorities, as you say, chose a different approach.  Maslow: if you want to trap a condition where your source data has duplicate keys, you'll have to write your own code to do so.  It's not much work.

Answer (score 3):

You could shadow the built-in `dict` function with a version that behaves as you want. You could return the more fitting `IReadOnlyDictionary` interface while you're at it.

```
let dict source =
    let d = Dictionary<'K, 'V>(HashIdentity.Structural)
    source |> Seq.iter d.Add
    { 
        new IReadOnlyDictionary<'K, 'V> with
            member x.ContainsKey(key) = d.ContainsKey(key)
            member x.TryGetValue(key, value) = d.TryGetValue(key, &value)
            member x.Item with get key = d.[key]
            member x.Keys = d.Keys :> _
            member x.Values = d.Values :> _
        interface IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<'K, 'V>> with
            member x.Count = d.Count
        interface IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<'K, 'V>> with
            member x.GetEnumerator() = d.GetEnumerator() :> _
        interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
            member x.GetEnumerator() = d.GetEnumerator() :> _
    }
```

Comment: Why not just cast the dictionary rather than wrapping it?

Comment: Wrapping provides a stronger guarantee of immutability, since you _could_ cast back to `Dictionary` and mutate.

Comment: But the object returned by `dict` is not a `Dictionary`, and it is [already immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) ("Builds a read-only lookup table from a sequence of key/value pairs").

Comment: But (after I checked the source code, I realized that) the object returned by `dict` also does not implement `IReadOnlyDictionary` so if you want to return an implementation of that interface, you cannot cast it, and you need to roll it yourself after all.

Answer (score 1):

I can't *explain* the reason for this design - just as I can't *explain* [why `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't take a sequence of `KeyValuePairs` as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2252920/126014).

However, if you look at the implementation of `dict`, you'll see that it internally adds each element using the indexer, like this:

```
foreach (Tuple<TKey, TValue> tuple in keyValuePairs)
{
    TValue local = tuple.Item2;
    TKey local2 = tuple.Item1;
    d[new RuntimeHelpers.StructBox<TKey>(local2)] = local;
}
```

where `d` is the `Dictionary` being created. The indexer silently updates the dictionary entry, so this explains the mechanics of it.

Not an entire answer, I admit, but perhaps a piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get a why unless some Microsoft engineer explains it to you why they chose to do it that way. Regardless, it is what it is and works just as the documentation says it should:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Remarks

You can also use the Item property to add new elements by setting the value
of a key that does not exist in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>; for example, 
myCollection[myKey] = myValue (in Visual Basic, myCollection(myKey) = 
myValue). However, if the specified key already exists in the 
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, setting the Item property overwrites the old 
value. In contrast, the Add method throws an exception if a value with the 
specified key already exists.
```